# Entropy of sum of two Uniform random variables

Tags: random-variables, entropy

say $X$ and $Y$ are two identical, independent and discrete Uniform random variables and $Z=X+Y$. I do not know more about the random variables.

Assuming $H(\cdot)$ to be the entropy of a random variable, I know that $H(Z) \geq \max\{H(X),H(Y)\}$. However, I wonder if a tighter bound exists given $X$ and $Y$ are discrete Uniform random variables?

any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Op wrote: `I do not know more about the random variables` ... Well, how about some more detail about the domain of support?  Does it start at 0, or 1, or take negative values?

Comment: the two independent random variables are symmetric around zero and zero itself is one instant of the random variables too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt. We're using this definition for $H(X)$, for a discrete r.v. $X$ with probabilities $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n$:
$$
H(X)=-\sum_{i=1}^n p_i \log_2(p_i)
$$

We know that the sum of two i.i.d. discrete uniform r.v. is a discrete triangular r.v., call it $Z$. $Z$ is symmetrical, so even though the support extends to $2n$ we need only to evaluate the sum until midway. We also know that the probabilities $z_i$ of $Z$ are $\frac{1}{n^2}, \frac{2}{n^2},\ldots,\frac{n}{n^2},\frac{n-1}{n^2},\ldots,\frac{1}{n^2}$. Hence, we have,
$$
\begin{aligned}
H(Z) &= -2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} z_i \log_2(z_i) - z_n \log_2(z_n)\\
     &= -2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{i}{n^2} \log_2 \left( \frac{i}{n^2} \right) -\frac{n}{n^2}\log_2 \left( \frac{n}{n^2}\right) \\
     &= - \frac{2}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i [\log_2(i) - 2\log_2(n)] + \frac{\log_2(n)}{n}\\
     &= - \frac{2}{n^2} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i \log_2(i) - 2\log_2(n) \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i \right) + \frac{\log_2(n)}{n}\\
     &= - \frac{2}{n^2} \left[\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \log_2(i^i) - 2\log_2(n) \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \right] + \frac{\log_2(n)}{n}\\
     &= \frac{2(n-1) \log_2(n)}{n}- \frac{2}{n^2} \log_2 \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} i^i  \right) + \frac{\log_2(n)}{n}\\
     &= \frac{(2n-1) \log_2(n)}{n}- \frac{2}{n^2} \log_2 \mathcal{H}(n-1).
\end{aligned}
$$
In the derivation, $\mathcal{H}(x)$ is the [hyperfactorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Hyperfactorial) function. And you'll probably need to adjust the formula if $n$ is odd.

As a check, if $n=6$ (a fair dice), then the information entropy associated with the event that observes the sum of two dice is about $3.2744$ (checked with WolframAlpha). I am not familiar with this area, so I do not know if this is the actual result, but it seems reasonable.

Comment: Re your check:  if $n = 6$ (fair dice), with $X  = {1,2,3,4,5,6}$, I get that the entropy of $Z=X+Y$ is:  $\log \left(6 \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^{5/18} 3^{2/3}\right)$ which is approximately 2.269 ... different to your result of 3.27.

Comment: Thank you for the answers.
 $3.2744$ is the exact entropy of the sum of two dice events $H(Z)$. the entropy of single dice event is $2.5850$ ($H(X) =2.5850 $) and so $2.269$ can not be a reasonable bound as $2.585$ is a known lower bound.

Comment: @MehdiXoylu Well, no. The entropy of a single dice, $X$, with pmf $f(x)$, calculated as $E[-log(f(x)]$ is $log(6)  \approx 1.79176$ ... By contrast, in your comment above, you appear to be calculating entropy with log base 2 which yields entropy of $log(6)/log(2)  \approx 2.58496$ ... Your question does not state that you wish to define entropy using base 2.

Comment: @wolfies - This website seems to support my calculation: http://math.ucsd.edu/~wgarner/math187/entropy_dice.htm. And yes, as it can be seen from my answer, I did work in base 2, which is consistent with information entropy.

Comment: Howdy @baudolino Yes - using base 2, I get for the sum of two dice that entropy is $$\frac{\log (28563737812992)+5 \log \left(\frac{36}{5}\right)}{18 \log (2)}$$ which is approx 3.2744. So all in agreement. We were just using different bases :) I have always used base e for entropy calculations, but the Wiki page notes that base 10 and base 2 are also in common use.

Answer (score 0):

Baudolino's solution was a good hint to derive the exact entropy of sum of two uniforms.
I assume $X$ and $Y$ are two discrete, independent uniformly distributed r.v. 
I make a further assumption and assume that both $X$ and $Y$ are symmetric around zero and zero itself is a member of the r.v.; therefore $X$ and $Y$ have $2n+1$ members with equal pmf and $Z$ has $4n+1$ entries.

As the pmf of sum of two random variables is the convolution of pmfs:

$f_Z(z)=\int\limits_{-2n}^{2n} f_X(\tau)f_Y(z-\tau)\mathrm{d}z$

Consequently:

Prob($Z=0$) = $(2n+1)(\frac{1}{2n+1})^2$,

Prob($Z=-1$) = Prob($Z=1$) = $(2n)(\frac{1}{2n+1})^2$

Prob($Z=-2$) = Prob($Z=2$) = $(2n-1)(\frac{1}{2n+1})^2$

$\vdots$

Prob($Z=-2n$) = Prob($Z=2n$) = $(\frac{1}{2n+1})^2$

and so, $H(Z)=2(\frac{1}{2n+1})^2 \log (2n+1)$ + $\sum\limits_{t=1}^{n} (\frac{2}{2n+1})^2  (2n+1-t) \log ({2n+1})$

$H(Z)= (\frac{2}{2n+1})^2 \Big( \frac{1}{2}+\sum\limits_{t=1}^{n} (2n+1-t) \Big) \log ({2n+1})$